# Form doesn't validate and submit in yii

Tags: php, jquery, forms, yii

I try load form via ajax in CJuiDialog. The form was success loaded but when I submitted form or write text, form not validate and not submit.I tried set "true" fourth parameter in renderPartialbut after then dialog window didn't open. In console, I got error

> $(...).dialog is not a function

In view I have this:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
       "test",
       "jQuery.ajax({ 
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '".$this->createUrl("/Site/ShowForm")."',
                 success: function(html){
                            $('#form-test').html(html);
                            });
                             ",
                          CClientScript::POS_READY); ?>
        <div id="form-test"></div>
<?php  $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
```

My actions in controller:

```
  public function actionShowForm()
{

            $model = new RegistrationForm;

             if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest )
              return $this->renderPartial('register', array('model' => $model),false,false);

    }       

          public function actionRegister()
{   
    $model = new RegistrationForm;
            $this->ajaxValidate($model);
            $model->attributes =$_POST['RegistrationForm'];
            if($model->validate())
            {
                $user = new User;
                $user->attributes = $model->attributes;
                if($user->save())
                echo 1;
            }
}
```

and my form (register.php)

```
<?php
            $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id' => 'register-form',
                //'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'clientOptions'        => array(
                        //'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                        'validateOnChange' => true
                ),
                'action' => array('site/Register'),
            ));
            ?>

            <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>



            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'first_name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'first_name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model, 'first_name'); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'last_name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'last_name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model, 'last_name'); ?>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'email'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->emailField($model, 'email'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model, 'email'); ?>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'password'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'password'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model, 'password'); ?>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'Repeat password'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'repeat_password'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model, 'repeat_password'); ?>

            </div>
            <div>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'verifyCode'); ?>
                <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model, 'verifyCode'); ?>
            </div>



            <div class="row buttons">
                <?php
                echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Register', $this->createUrl("/Site/Register"), array(

                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'dataType' => 'json',
                    'success' => 'js:function(data){       
                                   if(data == 1){
                                    window.location ="' . $this->createUrl('site/index') . '"
                                   }
                         }',
                ));
                ?>

                     </div>

                <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

How Can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, where you check if the request is Ajax, you should be doing the Ajax validation in there.

Comment: It's not worked, when I put this->ajaxValidate($model); in showaction after renderPartial method I got simple text like this "{"RegistrationForm_first_name":["First Name cannot be blank."],"RegistrationForm_ ...". Besides SwhoAction must show only form

Answer (score 1):

I found solution! I added

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap = array(
                'jquery.js'     => false,
                'jquery.ui.js'  => false,
                'jquery.yiiactiveform.js' => false,
            );
```

in my actionShowForm.